# Grails - Spring security Third part API java.security.cert.CertificateException

Tags: api, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to use a few apis from sandboxapic.cisco.com. But i get java.security.cert.CertificateException when i try to authenticate.

I am using rest api and have tried the sample grails third party application.

Comment: Please include an example of what you have tried before

Comment: I'm using  RestResponse restResponse = rest.post(url) {
            contentType "application/json"
            json([
                    username: "admin",
            password:"test!"
            ])
        }

I have tried the same post in an online API tester, and get the desired value. When run in grails.. i always get a 401, unauthorized issue.